# Python - Defensive programing on key errors

Tags: python, keyerror

I keep having a error on this same function and I can't figure out why. I thought i fix it the second time but not seeing why this still any issue. The error pops up once and while.

This was my first error but I fix it.

```
  File "running.py", line 332, in run
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable ================================================================================
05Oct 03:06:48: Exit status: 1
```

This is my current code

```
def get_notifyees(jobdef):
    origNotifyeesList = jobdef['notifyees'] if isinstance(jobdef['notifyees'], list) or jobdef['notifyees'] is None else [jobdef['notifyees']]
    origNotifyeesList = origNotifyeesList if origNotifyeesList is not None else []
    notifyeesList = []
    for notifyee in origNotifyeesList:
        if 'noreply' not in notifyee:
            notifyeesList.append(notifyee)
    return notifyeesList
```

But I'm getting this error now

```
File "running.py", line 337, in get_notifyees
KeyError: 'notifyees'
================================================================================
10Oct 01:53:03: Exit status: 1
```

Comment: Holy contorted logic, Batman! But seriously - it appears that `jobdef` doesn't have an entry with the key `"notifyees"`...

Comment: Rather than access `jobdef['notifyees']` in *4* different places, use a temp variable to factor that out of the first line.

Comment: try using `try` and expect `except`. BTW, I don't think assigning `notifyees` both item value and list is a good idea. It adds vulnerability because you have to check `iterabliity`.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
origNotifyeesList = jobdef['notifyees'] if isinstance(jobdef['notifyees'], list) or jobdef['notifyees'] is None else [jobdef['notifyees']]
```

This will raise a `KeyError` if `notifyees` is not a key in `jobdef`.
You can catch the exception, or you can check `if 'notifyees' in jobdef` around where you try and use the key.

Comment: Would you rewrite the function?

Comment: Yes, if it were my code I would rewrite the function.

Comment: Any recommendation? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/65274/python-rewriting-a-ugly-function